# Не отображается изображение на виджете

Tags: python, python-3.x, qt, pyqt5, виджет

Изображение на QScene не отображается на QGraphicsView. Также пробовал использовать QLabel и неудачно.

Без использования виджета картинку отобразить получается, но с его использованием QGraphicScene или QLabel оказывается пустым, но текст там выводится. Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем может заключаться проблема?

Нерабочий вариант с использованием QScene, QGraphicsView, QWidget:

```
  from PyQt5.QtGui import *
  from PyQt5.QtCore import QUrl
  from PyQt5.QtNetwork import QNetworkAccessManager, QNetworkRequest
  from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QLabel, QWidget, QVBoxLayout, QGraphicsScene, QGraphicsView
  import sys

 class Widget(QWidget):

  def __init__(self):
     super().__init__()
     self.initUI()

  def initUI(self):
     self.setGeometry(50,50,500,500)
     url = "http://pp.vk.me/c627626/v627626428/be07/wbpWha0RqZ4.jpg"
     self.scene = QGraphicsScene()
     self.mainImage = QGraphicsView()
     self.nam = QNetworkAccessManager()
     self.nam.finished.connect(self.finishRequest)
     self.nam.get(QNetworkRequest(QUrl(url)))
     layout = QVBoxLayout()
     layout.addWidget(self.mainImage)
     self.setLayout(layout)
     self.show()

  def finishRequest(self, reply):
     img = QImage()
     img.loadFromData(reply.readAll())
     self.item = QGraphicsPixmapItem(QPixmap.fromImage(img))
     self.scene.addItem(self.item)
     self.scene.setSceneRect(img.rect())
     self.mainImage.setScene(self.scene)


  if __name__ == '__main__': 
     app = QApplication(sys.argv)
     ex = Widget()
     ex.show()

     sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Нерабочий вариант с использованием QLabel, QWidget:

```
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import QUrl
from PyQt5.QtNetwork import QNetworkAccessManager, QNetworkRequest
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QLabel, QWidget, QVBoxLayout
import sys

class Widget(QWidget):

  def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()
    self.initUI()

  def initUI(self):
    url = "http://pp.vk.me/c627626/v627626428/be07/wbpWha0RqZ4.jpg"
    self.lbl = QLabel("loading...")
    self.lbl.setAutoFillBackground(True)
    nam = QNetworkAccessManager()
    nam.finished.connect(self.finishRequest)
    nam.get(QNetworkRequest(QUrl(url)))
    self.layout = QVBoxLayout()
    self.layout.addWidget(self.lbl)
    self.setLayout(self.layout)
    self.show()

  def finishRequest(reply):
    img = QImage()
    img.loadFromData(reply.readAll())
    self.lbl.setPixmap(QPixmap.fromImage(img))

 if __name__ == '__main__': 
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Widget()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Рабочий вариант с QLabel, но без QWidget:

```
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import QUrl
from PyQt5.QtNetwork import QNetworkAccessManager, QNetworkRequest
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QLabel

app = QApplication([])
url = "http://pp.vk.me/c627626/v627626428/be07/wbpWha0RqZ4.jpg"
lbl = QLabel("loading...")
nam = QNetworkAccessManager()

def finishRequest(reply):
    img = QImage()
    img.loadFromData(reply.readAll())
    lbl.setPixmap(QPixmap(img))

nam.finished.connect(finishRequest)
nam.get(QNetworkRequest(QUrl(url)))
lbl.show()
app.exec_()
```

Comment: А картинка вообще есть? Попробуйте ее сохранить и убедиться что она в порядке: `img.save("img.jpg")`. Еще проблема может быть в том, что плагины для изображений почему то не нашлись

Comment: Касаемо QLabel, setAutoFillBackground в true пробовали ставить?

Comment: @gil9red, попробовал сохранить - не получается, проверка print(b = img.save("img.jpg")) ничего не выводит.

Comment: @free_ze, попробовал, не помогло

Comment: Листинг кода варианта с QLabel: https://pp.vk.me/c836227/v836227428/159ea/w2lUtiWQfvQ.jpg

Я так полагаю проблема заключается в передаче параметра reply методу finishRequest, только не понимаю где именно ошибка.

Рабочий листинг кода без виджета:
https://pp.vk.me/c836227/v836227428/159f1/MYwZhAKWKos.jpg

Comment: Лучше приложите код в ваш вопрос

Comment: Мне вот интересно... эта картинка находится в vk, и мне почему-то верится, что чтобы получить ее, нужно будет сначала авторизоваться в vk (или в запросе передавать необходимые куки)

Comment: @gil9red, я попробовал изменить ссылку на изображение на http://img1.liveinternet.ru/images/attach/c/0/113/541/113541493_0_7dc00_38c66c03_L.jpg .Ничего не изменилось. Да и в третьем варианте приложения в моем посте изображение корректно грузится, поэтому проблема вовсе не в самой картинке.

Comment: Понял. Дело в `nam` и это объяснит почему третий вариант грузится. Когда вы объявляете `nam` он будет автоматический удален сборщиком мусора, т.к. на него нет ссылок. Поэтому, объявите его полем класса `self.nam` и так используйте. В третьем варианте `nam` будет жить пока скрипт работает, поэтому картинка загрузилась

Comment: @gil9red, я что-то совсем туплю, объявил nam полем класса - теперь виджет вылетает, значит какая-то ошибка снова.

Comment: @gil9red, после объявления nam полем класса стал виджет вылетать

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблему я увидел в функции `finish_request`, там у вас передавался один параметр – `reply`, но методы объектов в питоне всегда первым параметром принимают `self` – указатель на объект класса, его аналогом будет `this` в `с++`

Когда я ваш код вставил в IDE (PyCharm) то она сразу выделила в той функции, что не знает откуда в ней взялась переменная `self`, что, собственно было и правильно.

```py
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPixmap
from PyQt5.QtCore import QUrl
from PyQt5.QtNetwork import QNetworkAccessManager, QNetworkRequest
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QLabel, QWidget, QVBoxLayout


class Widget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.lbl = QLabel("loading...")
        self.lbl.setAutoFillBackground(True)

        self.nam = QNetworkAccessManager()
        self.nam.finished.connect(self.finish_request)

        url = "http://pp.vk.me/c627626/v627626428/be07/wbpWha0RqZ4.jpg"
        self.nam.get(QNetworkRequest(QUrl(url)))

        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.lbl)

        self.setLayout(layout)

    def finish_request(self, reply):
        img = QPixmap()
        img.loadFromData(reply.readAll())

        self.lbl.setPixmap(img)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication([])

    w = Widget()
    w.show()

    app.exec()
```

---

Со сценой:

```py
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPixmap
from PyQt5.QtCore import QUrl
from PyQt5.QtNetwork import QNetworkAccessManager, QNetworkRequest
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (
    QApplication, QWidget, QVBoxLayout, QGraphicsScene, 
    QGraphicsView, QGraphicsPixmapItem, QGraphicsTextItem
)


class Widget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.scene = QGraphicsScene()
        self.scene.addItem(QGraphicsTextItem('loading...'))

        self.view = QGraphicsView()
        self.view.setScene(self.scene)

        self.nam = QNetworkAccessManager()
        self.nam.finished.connect(self.finish_request)

        url = "http://pp.vk.me/c627626/v627626428/be07/wbpWha0RqZ4.jpg"
        self.nam.get(QNetworkRequest(QUrl(url)))

        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.view)

        self.setLayout(layout)

    def finish_request(self, reply):
        self.scene.clear()

        img = QPixmap()
        img.loadFromData(reply.readAll())

        item = QGraphicsPixmapItem(img)
        self.scene.addItem(item)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication([])

    w = Widget()
    w.show()

    app.exec()
```

Comment: спасибо за ответ, теперь работает, только вариант с QScene, QGraphicsView все еще не работает, я его исправил в соответствии с вашими поправками.

Comment: Не знаю в чем у вас там может быть проблема :) вроде бы код еще маленький и прозрачный
Если ищите ошибку, то: логируйте в коде, используйте отладчик

Comment: большое спасибо, попозже разберу в чем была проблема, у меня просто отладчика нет, пока лень устанавливать, да и времени нет.